# VBA to make it just to the next line and include the if statement above

Tags: vba, excel

I have an item number scanned into excel B4 and based on the number, it returns either "Yes" or "No" into C4. If it says "Yes" I would like the item number in B4 to be added to another sheet. If it says "No", nothing needs to happen with this item number. I would like the items numbers to from a list in the separate sheet.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Yes",Sheet7!C4)),Sheet7!B4,)
```

My if statement is working fine but the issue now lies with a code to make jump to the next row after data has been changed so this can be a continuous process. Right now, after something has been scanned, it provides me with that value i need but as soon as another item is scanned it changes the value to the newest. i want a list of item numbers in the end

Comment: Post the code for more help.

Comment: Of course, try to anonymize it the best you can.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the code for you but look at events.

To get to these open the VBA window [Alt] + [F11] then go onto the sheet you want the event to action on.

Change the top left Drop Down to "Worksheet" and the top right will then let you select different events. for this I would recommend the 'Change' event, this causes the code to trigger whenever a cell is changed.

[image: Screenshot of VBA window with events drop down open]